# Teradata returning Division by Zero Error - How to Adress?

Tags: sql, teradata, divide-by-zero

The following query utilizes a case statement with some division. However, it is getting snagged on a division  by zero error. Any ideas on how to handle the error exception would be greatly appreciated!

```
CASE 
    WHEN Channel = 'DA' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID) 
    WHEN Channel = 'SS' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID) 
    WHEN Channel = 'XDOCK' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID)
    WHEN Channel = '?' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID) 
    ELSE 0
    END AS Percentage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `NULLIF`. Additionally you can simplify your query to:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Channel IN ('DA','SS','XDOCK','?') 
      THEN Cast(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/NullIf(Sum(Cast(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) Over (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID),0) 
    ELSE 0
END AS Percentage
```

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error "expected something between ')' and ')'

Comment: @Jeremy: Ops, forgot the `,0`, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with another case

```
  CASE  WHEN SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2)) <> 0 THEN
              WHEN Channel = 'DA' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID)
        THEN -1 /*  or the value you prefer for zero value */
        END
   ....
```